# Iframe/Popup redirecting opener window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, popup, window.open

I have a page located at x.com.  On this page is a button that, when clicked, will launch a new window (using javascript's window.open() method) to a page that is located at z.com.  The popup does a few things, then redirects the original window (the opener, x.com) to a different page based on some parameters defined in the popup.

This works fine in Firefox/Chrome, but not in IE.  In IE (8 specifically, but I believe 7 also has this problem) the original window (the opener) is not redirected.  Instead, a new window comes up and THAT window is redirected.

I've tried many different methods to try and get this to work, including changing the popup to an iframe loaded on the page and having a function on the opener that the popup/iframe call.  The problem seems to be that IE refuses to allow cross-domain sites to talk to each other via javascript.

Is there a way around this?  How can I get the parent window to redirect to a page based on parameters in a popup or iframe?

**EDIT:**

Here is some code for samples:

In a page on domainA.com, I have this:

```
<img src='/images/test.png' onclick="window.open('http://www.domainB.com/item.aspx', 'name', 'width=100,height=100,menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no');" />
```

In item.aspx on domainB.com I have this in the javascript:

```
opener.location.href = 'http://www.somethingelse.com/';
```

In Firefox/Chrome, this works fine.  In IE, when domainB.com tries to set location.href on opener (aka the parent window, which is domainA.com), it instead opens a new window, which is not what I want.  I want it to redirect the opener (parent window) to the URL I specified.

Bara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving it by doing the following:

I added an iFrame to my main page.  The iFrame is in the same domain as my popup.  The iFrame contains a button that, when clicked, will launch the popup.

The popup does it's thing, then changes the iFrame's hash tag to something like #change (so the url would be www.whatever.com/iframe.aspx#change).   In the iFrame's javascript, I have a loop going that checks the hash to see if it says "change" and if so, it will redirect the parent page to wherever I want.  This works beautifully.

Because I did not want the infinite loop on every single page, I do a browser check so that this only applies to IE.  For all other browsers I just use window.opener which works fine.

Bara

Answer (score 3):

Hi I solved my problem by doing the following
instead of using window.opener.location = "....

Use **window.opener.document.location** = "url". This worked for me.

Another thing is make sure that you are **not redirecting from http into https** this will also cause it to break.

Cheers

Comment: getting permission denied message :(